# Radon measure, Integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $d \geq1$ and $D\subset \mathbb{R}^{d}$ be open

In the following, $J$ is a symmetric positive radon measure on $D\times D \setminus \operatorname{diag} $, where $\operatorname{diag}=\{(x,x)\mid x \in U \}  $, such that for all $u \in C_{0}^{\infty}(D)$

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{D \times D \setminus \operatorname{diag}} |u(x)-u(y)|^{2}J(dx,dy)<\infty \tag{*}
\end{eqnarray*}

I want to prove $(*)$ is equivalent with
\begin{eqnarray*}
\text{for all compact sets }K\text{ and open sets } U \text{ with } K\subset U\subset D \\
\int_{K \times K \setminus \operatorname{diag} } |x-y|^{2}J(dx,dy)< \infty\,,\,J(K,D \setminus U)< \infty\\
\tag{**}
\end{eqnarray*}

---

My thinking:

$(**) \Rightarrow (*)\,({\rm for\,example}\,d=1) $:

$\forall K$, compact, $\exists M>0$ s.t. $|u(x)-u(y)|\leq M|x-y| \quad(x,y\in K) $　(mean-value theorem). Hence 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{K\times K \setminus \operatorname{diag} } |u(x)-u(y)|^{2} J(dx,dy)\leq M^{2} \int_{K\times K \setminus \operatorname{diag} } |x-y|^{2} J(dx,dy) < \infty
\end{eqnarray*}

but this does not imply $(*)$. 　I don't really understand how to use $J(K,D \setminus U)< \infty$.

$(*)\Rightarrow(**)$

If there exists $(u_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that  $\int_{K \times K \setminus \operatorname{diag}} |(x-y)-(u_{n}(x)-u_{n}(y))|^{2} J(dx,dy) \to 0 \quad(n \to \infty)  $, then I can 
get $\int_{K\times K \setminus \operatorname{diag} } |x-y|^{2} J(dx,dy) < \infty$. But is sequence like this is really exists? Also how do I get $J(K,D \setminus U) < \infty$?

Please give me a clue.

Comment: Your first expression is preceded by "such that." Such that what? The expression isn't given as equal to anything.

Comment: Nvm, I think I figured it out. I edited for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

For the other direction, you know that $K\subseteq U\subseteq D$ with $U$ open, so you can approximate $1_K\times 1_K$ times the identity funciton, call this function $f$, by smooth functions with compact support so that the difference between the integral against $f$ is $<\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon >0$. Call $u$ the smooth, compactly supported approximation to $f$. Then by the first condition, we have the estimate

$$\left|\int_{D\times D\setminus\text{diag}}|x-y|^2 \cdot 1_K\times 1_K\, J(dx,dy)-\int_{D\times D\setminus\text{diag}}|u(x)-u(y)|^2\, J(dx,dy)\right|<\epsilon$$

so by the triangle inequality, we get

$$\int_{K\times K\setminus\text{diag}}|x-y|^2\, J(dx,dy)=$$
$$\int_{D\times D\setminus\text{diag}} |x-y|^2\cdot 1_K\times 1_K\, J(dx,dy)<\int_{D\times D\setminus\text{diag}}|u(x)-u(y)|^2\,J(dx,dy)+\epsilon$$

hence convergence and the implication in the other direction.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is very useful!